# Is This Linear Functional Bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

In the space of $L^1[0,1]$, is the following linear functional $I：L^1[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:

$$
I(f) = \int_0^1 x^3f(x)dx
$$

bounded on this section of the norm ball $\{f:\|f\|_1 = 1 \text{ and } f(x) > 0, \forall x\}$?

---

Update: If $I$ is bounded, then the following optimization problem must have a solution:

$$
\max_f I(f)\\
s.t. \|f\|_1 = 1, f > 0,\\
 \int_0^1xf(x)dx = a,\\
 \int_0^1x^2f(x)dx = b.
$$

**What is the solution to this problem**?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, something stronger:

> **Lemma** Let $X$ and $Y$ normed spaces. Then $T:X\to\mathbb{Y}$ is bounded (in the classical sense: there is $M>0$ such that $\|Tx\|\le
>  M\|x\|$ for all $x\in X$) if and only if $T$ maps bounded sets into
>   bounded sets.
>
> *Proof* Suppose $T$ bounded. Let $A\subseteq X$ a bounded set. Then, there is $N>0$ such that $\|x\|\le N$ for all $x\in A$. Thus
>   $\|Tx\|\le\|T\|\|x\|\le\|T\|N$, so $T(A)$ is a bounded set on $Y$.
>
> For the reciprocal, let $B=\{x\in X\,|\,\|x\|\le 1\}$. Then $B$ is
>   bounded, so $T(B)$ is bounded on $Y$. That is, there is $N>0$ such
>   that $\|Tx\|\le N$ for all $x$ with $\|x\|<1$. So $T$ is bounded.

Now, since the set $\{f\,|\,\|f\|=1\mbox{ and }f(x)>0\}$ is bounded, if we proove that $I$ is bounded, done. But

$|I(f)|=\left|\int_0^1x^3f(x)dx\right|\le\int_0^1|x^3||f(x)|dx\le\int_0^1|f(x)|dx=\|f\|$, so $I$ is bounded.

Thus $I$ is bounded on $\{f\,|\,\|f\|=1\mbox{ and }f(x)>0\}$ (on both senses: $f$ is continuous in this set and there is an $N>0$ such that $|I(f)|\le N$ for all $f$ in that set).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I updated my question. The problem actually comes from an optimization problem which I couldn't find a solution. Then I guess maybe its because the objective is not bounded. But now you showed that it is bounded, which basically says a solution exist. But how?

Comment: So, what are you meaning for "$I$ is bounded/unbounded"?

Comment: I mean $I(f) \le M$, for some $M > 0$. May you take a look at my updated question?